# Is it possible to automatically update Google My Business information from a website?

Tags: php, google-my-business-api

I am creating a website with a Google My Business account. I was wondering if it is possible to link the information from either the website to update the Google My Business account, or to have the Google My Business account update the website.

If it's possible, what is the best approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Does this help: https://support.google.com/business/answer/6333473?hl=en-GB ?

Comment: It helps because that's something I was unaware of, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't tell Google my business to search your website after that information.
Sometimes user will propose new informations.

But you can update google my business with the [Google my Business API](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6333473?hl=en-GB) yourself.